Movie about creating a world
There is an old movie that I want to watch again. I think it's a 2000's movie, and it's in English. Maybe a movie from England or the US.
The story is about 2 guys who create a virtual world and they can enter the world. A guy found that there is a bug in their program and he sent a letter in the virtual world. His friend visits the location and found that the bug's not just in their virtual world but even in their real world. In the end this guy realizes that they also live in a digital world and he takes over the body of the user who controls his body.

Year? Country\language? And where did you see it?

@Walt : I think 20's movies, and its english. Maybe England or US movie. Im not quite remember where I watch it.

OK, added (I assumed you meant 2000's).

This should be the movie The Thirteenth Floor
They build a complete VR-Simulation of Los Angeles in 1937. In the "real world" there happen some murder, later the main protagonist detect that their world is also only VR, and he commited the murders when he was controlled by a user of the "real real world". He takes control over the body of the user and can life in the "real real world" with the wife of the user, which also prefers his VR-personality against the personality the user had before.




Thank you very much. I remember the name of this guy is Douglass. Yeah this is it. Once again... thank you :D

Here I thought the 13th Floor was a paranormal thriller. Time to rent it.
